# jQuery UI Dialog doesn't set "left" property in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

For some reason, when I try to use jQuery dialog in IE9, it doesn't apply any `left` property to it leaving it at 0 which makes the dialog stay all the way to the left. It works fine in all other browsers including IE 7 and 8.

Here's the code for initializing and opening the dialog:

```
jQuery('#form-holder').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, closeOnEscape: true, width: 680, closeText: '', close: closeDialog
    });

jQuery('#form-holder').dialog('open');
```

I tried to apply the following code to manually set that property, but it didn't work either:

```
var ua = jQuery.browser;
if (ua.msie && ua.version.slice(0, 3) == "9.0") {
jQuery('div.ui-dialog').css('left', '294px');
}
```

The resulting HTML after opening the dialog:

```
<div tabIndex="-1" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-form-holder" style="left: 0px; top: 384px; width: 680px; height: auto; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1002; outline-width: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-color: invert;">
```

Is there any known compatibility issues of jQuery UI and IE9?

Comment: `div.ui-dialog` has been positioned absolutely?

Comment: Have you tried the `position: [294,384],` attribute of the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

try this, there is no need to use `px`, jQuery will take care of that;

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == '9.0') {
      $('div.ui-dialog').css('left', '294');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the position after open:

```
$("#form-holder").dialog( "option", "position", [294,384] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotation marks in the value passed to the top parameter in the jquery css function:

```
if (ua.msie && ua.version.slice(0, 3) == "9.0") {
jQuery('div.ui-dialog').css('left', 294);
}
```

Hope it helps!